# Something error apache python ImageGrab

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

When I use Django local test environment, there is no errors.

But I use apache2.2  and mod_wsgi, ImageGrab.grab() prompt errors.

IOError... screen grab failed

im = ImageGrab.grab()
size, data = grabber()
...

anyone who can help me how to solve this problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: Which operating system are you using when you are running it on the server?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  windows 7 64

Comment: I found any scripts run under windows service，the pil imagegrab will not work，is there any methods to do screenshot under windows service.